files permssion ownership change in kubernetes volume attached to application container
I have a use case, where we initially ran the container with root user so it created some file in volume with root ownership and rw-r--r-- permissions.
However now we want to run container with non root user but problem is we are unable to change ownership of existing files in volume which are owned by root. our entry point script runs via non root user so that not option for us to run chown during runtime.
I know this can be achieved by init or sidecar container, but looking for any other alternate method.
tried using the securityContext option in k8 yaml file
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1000


It depends on what CSI volume you are trying to bind mount. fsGroup in pod's securityContext is only to tell kubelet to try to change the ownership of the volume. Kubelet checks volume's fsType and access mode and make a guess to change ownership or not. Because it's a guess, it's fragile. Sig proposed a new design for CSI driver opt-in. This is GA in 1.23.
To answer this question, pls provide more information on volume and CSI driver.
